# How to print a double quote symbol in Red language

Tags: rebol, red

How can I print a double quote symbol ("). I tried different methods mentioned on http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/How-to-print-a-variable-with-in-double-quotes-td905186.html but they do not work:

```
print "\""
print as.character(x)  ; x should come in quotes
print dQuote(x)
```

How can this be done?

Comment: See [2.11.2 String Format](http://www.rebol.com/docs/core23/rebolcore-16.html#section-2.11.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two string formats... `{This is a string}` and `"This is too"`.  Escaping is done with a caret, `^`.

If you use the braces you worry less about escaping.  You can use single quotes, double quotes, and even braces if they are matched naturally.  `{This is {a valid} string}`.

So you can say `print {"}` or if you insist `print "^""`.  The former is usually preferable.

Comment: {string} is really convenient.

Comment: Angle brackets are also string delimiters.